# What does Kenneth Henshall mean by "X is used phonetically to express Y"?

Tags: kanji, etymology, linguistics

Henshall seems to have a quite specific idea about how many phonetic elements end up in characters, which diverges from explanations I find online, but I'm not sure I'm reading him correctly. Essentially, I'm wondering if he takes the view that for many characters, the sound was not strictly indicated by the 'phonetic component', but instead that a semantic link (a kind of ideograph) was created using a phonetic substitute.

An example from the list would be 映, where 日 is semantic and the radical, while 央 is said to be "acting phonetically to express bright". He says it is probably also lending its meaning, i.e. "centre" ('centre of sun' being especially 'bright'). This implies a distinction between "acting phonetically to express" a meaning, and "lending" a meaning.

In the introduction his explanation also implies this distinction. He says that the character 注 is made of 水 as the radical and 主, where 主 is a "phonetic element which expresses the sound of a word meaning continuous (specifically 続)".  He then glosses the character elements as signifying 'continuous' combined with 'water' (writing: "thus continuous (flow of) water").

To me this suggests that 主 is not to be understood as giving the sound for 注, but instead as providing a semantic element, "continuous", normally written as 続, using a simpler character which at some point had the same sound as 続. This is not because it couldn't be the case that 主 is both phonetic and semantic, but because of Henshall's actual phrasing of this explanation, which seems carefully set up to suggest that 主 is being used to *mean continuous*, by sounding like continuous, rather than give the sound for 注.

I'm not at all read up on scholarship around this of course, just curious to find this quite distinctive understanding of phonetic characters in this relatively standard book for helping learners understand Kanji origins. Does anyone know if I'm reading him right, and if so - is his an orthodox view of these phonetic elements?

Comment: Hernshall has it backwards, and his material isn’t standard by merit of scholarship, but...by being early to market.

Comment: *"a phonetic element which expresses the sound of a word meaning continuous"* -- this is how phonetic elements in Chinese characters are commonly explained, thus considered true. ︙ *主 gives the sound while also semantically suggesting continuous* -- this is your own claim, which is wrong and contrary to the first claim in which there is no "also". ︙ *this suggests that 主 is not to be understood as giving the sound for 注, but instead as providing a semantic element* -- this is a reasoning based on a false premise (your own claim), thus also false.

Comment: What edition do you have?  I'm looking at my dead-tree copy, fifth printing from 1990, and his text is different from what you've got: _"氵 is **water** 40. 主 is **master** 299 q.v., acting phonetically to express **continuous** and almost certainly lending an idea of **column** from its literal meaning of long stemmed lamp (see also 345 [柱]). Thus, **continuous column of water**, giving **pour**. Also used figuratively as pour one's thoughts, i.e. **pay attention**."_ No mention of 続, which is out of scope phonetically.

Comment: Thanks macraf - I've tried to correct the question on the basis of your comment, as I realise I didn't confirm that he also claims 'continuous' is to be included within the gloss. I also removed the erroneous claim you point out, but I was not basing my final assertion on that claim (instead I was suggesting he likely didn't mean that it is *both* a semantic and a phonetic element). My main query is more simply put as, how he can include 'continuous' in the gloss, unless 主 is acting semantically?

Comment: Thanks Eiríkr- this is from a 1998 edition, but the quotes I'm giving are from the introduction, rather than the character's section itself which I believe is what you quote above. In those he rarely gives the means whereby the phonetic element 'expresses' a meaning, but indeed, it was seeing 続 in the intro that confused me.

dROOze - I know I may be continuing a defunct discussion if he's simply wrong. The latest edition uses 'assoc' to add phonetic meanings instead of this phrasing, but fundamentally that doesn't seem to change the claim. Is there a comparable book that's most recommended?

Comment: I can't think of a book that does all of the following: (1) tries to explain Chinese characters in a linguistically sound manner and (2) gives a comprehensive list of glyph origins in a (3) mnemonic-style that's (4) in English and (5) is up-to-date with scholarship. I have several references that fulfils (1), (2) and (5), but they're in Chinese, so probably not useful for you.

Comment: Thanks again for this - it seems right then to view resources for learners as basically mnemonic aids in various costumes, good to know. I may stick with the scholarly costume to help the enterprise feel serious...